# Appending to end of line in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, editor

Is there a way to append string to the end of lines in Eclipse?
Search and find seems like it would work, but using find with just the regex expression `$` does not find any strings. `.$` will find something, but running find replace with this deletes the last character of your line, which is undesirable. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this in Eclipse? Is there something I am doing wrong with my regex that might make Eclipse not understand this, while other editors like vim handle it just fine..  (in Vi / Vim `:0,$s/$/appended to end of line/`).

Surely I am not the only person who wishes there was this functionality... It's offered by most other good editors. Could this be considered a bug?

Comment: What are you trying to append and why? Appending code to complete (;) lines makes for a lack of readability, something you will curse yourself for if you have to come back and edit the program later.

Comment: I am trying to append `";` to a list of final variables that are cut and pasted form another document. Dont worry, I will maintain readability...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree that this is a bug in eclipse.  I tried the same as you with the same results.  I also tried to use the regex search string "(?<=.)$" to try to ignore the single character match in the replace but that failed as well.  One should be able to search for end of string to append.

Here's a trick to make it work,

```
      Find: "(.)$"
      Replace: $1foo
```

This replaces the single character match before the end of line and appends foo.

That's a lot of hoop jumping but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the best bet would be to run a Java program on the list of variables before you copy them in. I'm not sure of the format of the file which you have cut and paste from but if it is just a list with only the variable names on each line, try this:

```
ArrayList<String> importarray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> rebuildarray = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader bufferedfile = new BufferedReader();

public static void main(String[] args) {
   readFile();
   processFile();
}

static void readFile() {

String file = "C:\\path\\file.txt";
try { 
    String line;
    importstart = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    for (line = importstart.readLine(); line != null; line = importstart.readLine()) {
        importarray.add (line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

 static void processFile() {
String complete = "";
for (String string : importarray) {
    complete = string + "\";";
    rebuildarray.add(complete);
}
  }
```

Adding this in would provide an array of variable names with " "; " on the end.

Alternatively, you could use this array in the String declaration and do:

```
for (String variable : rebuildarray) {
final String string = variable;
doSomething(string);
}
```

This would negate the need for the addition of ";.

Note sure if this is a bit too much, or even entirely what you were looking for, but they are a couple of ideas.

Comment: I accepted since you're the only person who tried to answer and I appreciate that sincerly. Dut this is a bit more work then im looking to do to solve this problem. It would be faster just to bite the bullet and type this stuff in by hand then write code to write my code for me :).

Comment: Thanks but I'm sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0), the accepted solution didn't work. It is only replacing the first line and leaving the others. But the worked (wanted to added a semi-colon):

```
find: ^.*$
Replace: $0;
```